# Opening Kubuntu DVD in Windows (EFI) gives message "Wubi doesn´t currently support EFI"

Tags: wubi, uefi, 14.10

After downloading an iso-image for Kubuntu 14.10 and then burning it to a DVD. When I then tried to open it I get this message:

[image]

What to do ?
Can anyone please help.

Comment: Help with what? WUBI does not support it. Probably never will. I would suggest a dual boot or use a virtual machine and install Ubuntu inside Windows like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: In a sense it's a duplicate, but it is a new popup message that may also be seen if you insert any Ubuntu DVD while running Windows on a computer with EFI firmware.

Comment: Before you close this, note that even someone who intends to perform a normal dual boot may see this popup if they insert the Ubuntu disk while running Windows (because wubi.exe is set to *autorun* on the disk). It's not specifically for someone wanting to use Wubi.

Comment: I'm leaving this open since it isn't an exact duplicate and I'm sure others will have similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new patch to Wubi introduced with Ubuntu 14.10 that spares users such as yourself who have computers with EFI firmware from installing Wubi only to find that it doesn't work. What used to happen is that the install would have appeared to succeed (in Windows), sometimes after downloading 1GB of data, only to find upon rebooting an error message about `wubildr.mbr` being corrupted.

Now Wubi checks and helpfully refuses to install, thus saving you a lot of pain. Do a normal dual boot as suggested here: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

**Note:**

Wubi.exe is also set to *autorun* when you insert an (K)Ubuntu DVD in Windows. Even if you don't intend to install Kubuntu using Wubi it will autorun and then terminate with this popup on EFI computers.

Answer (score 0):

See the forum staff recommendations for WUBI at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229766.  You can use a virtual machine, install to removable media like a usb disk or flash stick, or repartition your hard disk to make room for Ubuntu.  WUBI is not really an option any longer.